# Remote debugging using Visual Studio 2019 connected to Win2016

Tags: c#, visual-studio, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am just wondering if anyone could help me track down the cause of the "Visual Studio Remote Debugging Tool" failing on a C# app connecting to a remote Windows 2016 Operating system?

Just to let you know what I have done, I have [gone here and downloaded the Remote Tools for 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2019) and installed it successfully on the 2016 box.

On the server, I have also manually added the following firewall rules to open up port 4024 (just to be certain)

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="VisualStudio_Debug_4024_TCP_IN" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=4024
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="VisualStudio_Debug_4024_TCP_OUT" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP localport=4024
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="VisualStudio_Debug_4024_UDP_IN" dir=in action=allow protocol=UDP localport=4024
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="VisualStudio_Debug_4024_UDP_OUT" dir=out action=allow protocol=UDP localport=4024
```

On the server, when I run the "Visual Studio Remote Debugger", I run it as admin and when I connect in Visual studio I see my self connect to the "Remote Debugger App" thats running on the server just fine.

[image: remote debuuger running fine on server]

Then, on my laptop, in Visual Studio when I go to Debug->Attach to a process and enter the Win2016 server name, it does bring up the task list of all apps running on the server (although its a bit slow in brining up the list)

[image: attach to process works in vs]

But then, when I click "Attach", I get the spinny circle of death and finally this error pops up!

[image: error message from vs]

It says the remote debugger does not appear to be running on the remote machine, but it obviosuly is as its allows me to get the task list and I can also see myself connect in the UI of the "Remote Debuuger" on the server!!

I'm at a loss of what to do from here or what else it could be and am left scratchng my head. Does anyone know where else I could look to see what the problem could be?

Any help or direction would be greatly appeciated. Cheers.

Comment: Start from first principles: disable Windows Firewall **entirely** on **both** machines. If there is antivirus software running, disable that garbage too. Then retry the remote debugging session and if it succeeds, then you can start narrowing it down. [This might also be helpful](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugger/configure-the-windows-firewall-for-remote-debugging?view=vs-2019#allow-and-configure-the-remote-debugger-through-windows-firewall) - instead of manually allowing 20 billion different ports, just allow the app and whatever ports it needs will be auto-allowed.

Comment: Thanks for your commnent @Ian Kemp. Unfortunatley, turning off firewalls and antivirus all together is easier said than done.  This server is in a corporate network so you can imagine the number of hoops I would need to go through to diable the firewall and antivirus thats on the machine. If I raise the service ticket now, I might be able to update this SO post in 3 months time once its gone through technical board and change board!! :) - But I am just going to having a read of your attached link though now to see if there is any other details ive missed.  Thanks

Comment: Hi @IanKemp - Thanks!! That link you supplied got me to the answer.  It mentions on that page that ports 4024 *and* 4025 need to be open on the remote server!! I only opened up 4024.  When I opened up 4025 eveything started working! Let me know if you want to create an answer for this post and I will mark it as answered otherwise I can answer it myself.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Ian Kemp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70345/ian-kemp) for pointing me in the right direction on this one.

This [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/configure-the-windows-firewall-for-remote-debugging?view=vs-2019#ports-on-the-remote-computer-that-enable-remote-debugging) lists the ports on the remote computer that need to be opened before remote debugging will work. The ports you need to open are:

- Port 4024
- Port 4025
- Port 3702 (this is optional and I did not open this port myself)

Apparently for each new version of Visual Studio that gets released, the port number increments by 2.

I had opened port **4024** but not **4025**.  To open these ports I ran this batch file on the server and my local laptop.

```
REM Open Port 4024    
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="VisualStudio_Debug_4024_TCP_IN" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=4024
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="VisualStudio_Debug_4024_TCP_OUT" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP localport=4024
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="VisualStudio_Debug_4024_UDP_IN" dir=in action=allow protocol=UDP localport=4024
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="VisualStudio_Debug_4024_UDP_OUT" dir=out action=allow protocol=UDP localport=4024

REM Open Port 4025
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="VisualStudio_Debug_4025_TCP_IN" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=4025
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="VisualStudio_Debug_4025_TCP_OUT" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP localport=4025
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="VisualStudio_Debug_4025_UDP_IN" dir=in action=allow protocol=UDP localport=4025
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="VisualStudio_Debug_4025_UDP_OUT" dir=out action=allow protocol=UDP localport=4025
```

and hey-presto! It started working!